# How to escape an @ in source column in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have JSON files in Azure Storage which I want to stage to an Azure SQL Database with Azure Data Factory Copy activity.

[image: @ sign in columnname]

However, two column names have an @ sign as the first character. This results in an error when trying to run the pipeline.

[image: Error]

[image: More detailed error message]

How can I escape the @ symbol so that it does not evaluate the string as an expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#expressions
Based on this doc, you should use @@ to escape @